# How to create a 301 redirect based on a query string within a subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file in the root of a website:

```
/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/.htacess
```

and I have some files in

```
/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/folder/
```

which are currently generated by index.php?pc=1234

I want to redirect the numbers in the query string variable to static html pages within that folder. I can achieve this in the .htacess file in the root of the website by:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/\?pc=1 /folder/filename.html [R=301,L]
```

However as there are a few of these files, it would be useful if I could create a .htaccess file in:

```
/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/folder/.htaccess
```

My question is: How do I capture the querystring and redirect accordingly from this folder?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the redirect rules? ?pc=1 => filename.html, ?pc=2 => some_other_file.html, ?pc=3 => my_other_filename_that_does_not_really_correlate_to_th_number.html or more like ?pc=1 => 1.html, ?pc=2 => 2.html.

Comment: The first one:
?pc=1 => filename.html, ?pc=2 => some_other_file.html, ?pc=3 => my_other_filename_that_does_not_really_correlate_to_th_number.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Residuum and Nerdling. You guys gave me some ideas.

This was what I ended up with. The following in /var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/folder/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pc=1
RewriteRule ^$ filename.html? [R=301,L]
```

If I didn't include the RewriteBase the URL would appear as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/folder/
```

But with it appeared properly as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/folder/filename.html
```

I also had to create a rewrite rule which captured a blank filename i.e. "  ^$ " then delcare the filename i wanted pc=1 to go to.

Thanks again Residuum, Nerdling

Answer (score 2):

Before the RewriteRule for 301, place something like this:

> `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} MATCH`

where `MATCH` is whatever you want to match.  You can use multiple ones with the `[OR]` block at the end.

You can find more information at [Apache's website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond).

Answer (score 1):

In subfolders, only use the relative URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteRule ^\?pc=1 filename.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\?pc=2 someotherfilename.html [R=301,L]
```

Or Similar to using RewriteCond as Nerdling said, but using skip for your rewrite rules, like this:

```
# this will skip the two line for anything not matching ^folder/\?pc=
RewriteRule !^folder/\?pc= - [S=2] 
RewriteRule ^folder/\?pc=1 /folder/filename.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^folder/\?pc=2 /folder/someotherfilename.html [R=301,L]
# anything else will be interpreted again
```

Or use the rule for terminating interpretation for anything else:

```
RewriteRule !^folder/\?pc= - [L] 
RewriteRule ^folder/\?pc=1 /folder/filename.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^folder/\?pc=2 /folder/someotherfilename.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've tried using:

Or for your .htaccess in folder:

RewriteRule ^\?pc=1 filename.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\?pc=2 someotherfilename.html [R=301,L]

however it doesn't work. Have I got to "turn anything on" in order for it to work?

Comment: I've added in the RewriteBase however comes up with:
"/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/folder/
.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL"

Comment: I don't know why RewriteRule ^\?pc=1 filename.html [R=301,L]
Will work fine for querystrings in the root .htaccess, but not in the folder/.htacess. I think that's one of apache's mysteries